# How to I add intermediate sum columns to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a one column data frame containing a list of "winners" which looks like this:

```
+---+--------+
|   | Winner |
+---+--------+
| 0 | A      |
| 1 | C      |
| 2 | D      |
| 3 | D      |
| 4 | A      |
| 5 | B      |
+---+--------+
```

But I'm struggling to add intermediate score columns to this data frame. What I want to achieve is this:

```
+---+--------+---+---+---+---+
|   | Winner | A | B | C | D |
+---+--------+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | A      | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | C      | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | D      | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | D      | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | A      | 2 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | B      | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
+---+--------+---+---+---+---+
```

Is there any way to add these columns?

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to add that I would like pandas to generate these intermediate scores from that column. So I don't want to manually add them.

Comment: You've not posted or explained where these intermediate scores come from?

Comment: Have you tried just `df['A'] = [1,1,1,1,2,2]` ... etc?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I would like pandas to generate these intermediate scores from that column. So I don't want to manually add them.

Comment: @DaniëlFranke, updated my answer with a shorter, clearer appoach.

Answer (score 3):

Create an initial frame:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['A', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'B'], columns=['Winner'])
```

We will use the unique column names, so stash them:

```
>>> names = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D') # sorted(df["Winner"].unique().tolist())
```

Derive the "win" event frame:

```
>>> events = pd.DataFrame([[int(i==j) for i in names] for j in df["Winner"]],
                          columns=names)
```

The `events` looks like this:

```
>>> events
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  1  0
2  0  0  0  1
3  0  0  0  1
4  1  0  0  0
5  0  1  0  0
```

Now we can use pandas' [cumulative sum function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html).

```
>>> events.cumsum()
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  0  0
1  1  0  1  0
2  1  0  1  1
3  1  0  1  2
4  2  0  1  2
5  2  1  1  2
```

Finally, just join what you need:

```
>>> df.join(events.cumsum())
  Winner  A  B  C  D
0      A  1  0  0  0
1      C  1  0  1  0
2      D  1  0  1  1
3      D  1  0  1  2
4      A  2  0  1  2
5      B  2  1  1  2
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and also made pandas "click" in my head. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DaniëlFranke, if this answer solved your original question, please mark it as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks!